# What good resources exist for an inexperienced user to explain how to safely upgrade Ubuntu Mate to 18.10 from 18.04?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-mate

Firstly let me apologize for, what to many will be a very basic question, but I am an 81 year old newbie, who really enjoys using 18.04 MATE on my X550 ASUS laptop (12Gb RAM) without a great depth of knowledge.

I'd like to keep up to date via 18.10 to 19.04 and so on, but have been reading that I must save my home folder, make changes to PPA's etc., which concern me as I'm not confident enough. My real concern is loss of data and the setup I'm using.

I'm sure this has been dealt with before so could somebody direct me to some how to do it sites please, the simpler the better. I hate to be restricted through the fear of breaking something that is working well for me.

Comment: It is possible that there is a difference between Ubuntu-MATE and Ubuntu proper.  Are you active in the Mate forums?

Comment: Maybe you would prefer to skip the hassle of upgrading every release and instead upgrade only for LTS releases.

Comment: If the above link is too complicated, you could maybe try the official guide: [Upgrade Ubuntu desktop](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: I agree with @wjandrea that it may not be worth the hassle to upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10. 18.04 is an LTS release which means it will remain supported for years and you can upgrade directly from 18.04 to 20.04. If you upgrade to 18.10 you will have to upgrade twice a year until you get to 20.04.

Comment: You could even skip Ubuntu 20.04 and wait for Ubuntu 22.04 - Ubuntu 18.04 is supported for a long time...

Comment: Welcome 81yo! The comments from the others have their own validity. My comment is this... upgrading is usually pretty painless... but ALWAYS have good backups! The biggest complication is if you've added a number of other repositories/PPA's to your system, as the upgrade disables all third party repos/PPA's, and you must manually re-enable them after the upgrade... and this also sometimes requires manual editing of the "deb" lines that contain the repo distribution folders (Ubuntu release names... like bionic vs cosmic, etc). More on that later.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Last time I wanted to skip an LTS release I didn't manage to find a way to do it and ended up doing two upgrades back to back.

Comment: @kasperd My usual method is a complete reinstall - but then again I hit every release...  And muck with my system a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, Hal. Lots of older folks use Ubuntu, and lots of older folks are here on AskUbuntu. The kids here can be noisy...but kids have always been noisy.

"Keeping up to date" could mean two things - *security updates* or *latest-and-greatest* versions of software. A lot of people get the two mixed up, but there's a difference. Security updates keeps your system safe from many (not all) forms of hacking. Latest-and-greatest includes security updates plus new non-security features and changes. Some people dislike those changes, especially if a favorite feature gets hidden or removed.

ALL supported releases of Ubuntu get security updates. You don't need to worry about that. If you like your desktop the way it is right now, and don't want it to change, then stick to an LTS release of Ubuntu. If you want to see the new stuff, then try the standard every-6-month release of Ubuntu.

You SHOULD have a way to backup your personal data (located in /home) in case your machine gets clobbered by water or cats or kids or a power surge. Lots of ways to do that.

You DON'T need any separate partitions (with one exception for EFI, used for booting). You DON'T need a separate /boot, you DON't need to use PPAs. That kind of stuff is completely optional, do them only if you wish to. If you let the Ubuntu installer stick to the default choices, it will build you a nice, sane, usable system...and that's exactly what we recommend to most new users.

Some new users, after a few months, change their partitions, try PPAs, install another desktop flavor, or otherwise customize their system. But lots of people stick to the basic install quite happily for many years.

Comment: Thank you allso much for your very prompt replies. I wish I could select all f them for an "upvote" as I've taken bits for all of them. I do back up al my data off the laptop, photos, letters bookmarks etc., A hang over form Windows days. Thank you all once again I shall take heart from the fact you are all out there and so ready to help.